# Angular animations doesn't animate new component

Tags: angular, animation

I am trying to animate the creation/removal of a new angular component within my app.

I am following to Angular guide here: 
https://angular.io/guide/transition-and-triggers#enter-and-leave-aliases

Specifically, I am trying to animate the opacity (eg, fadeIn effect). I noticed that the animation seems to work fine on normal html elements (divs, etc), but when applied to an angular component it doesn't. I've created the following Stackblitz to demonstrate the problem.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9tvz1b

I would expect both blocks to animate the same way, however only the first one does. I've noticed that applying 0.5 opacity to the  element directly in the Devtools also has no effect. So is this just a limitation of HTML? I haven't been able to find any straight answers on this.

What would be the alternative solution to animating my component without having to query into the view itself, and animating its first child?

Answer (score 0):

how are you doing?

To animate Components, you should use the metadata `animations` as you did on your **AppComponent**. The way is already implemented Angular for that I think it gives you more flexibility in order to style components.

Normally, you will not have only a *div* in a Component, and possibly you would like animate them separately and invididually. As well, you could have Routing animations going on, so better to use `animations` metadata tag.

If you just want to reuse your animations in different components, that´s completely fine and quite easy actually.
You could share your trigger actions via a shared property.

I have forked your Stackblitz showing it: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-swvfdy

Cheers!!